# passing a simple variable in javascript (form)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am an inexperienced web developer writing a registration form using JS for client-side validation and PHP for server-side. I am stuck trying to just test a variable and make sure that it is getting passed to JS. I heard that jsfiddle doesn't like forms, so I restructured my fiddle code to not include any form tags. The code does not do anything when I run it. Can someone help please? Also, should I install Apache to test the form locally or would Chrome be able to handle it? I know that I'll have to eventually to test PHP, but I'm just trying to get JS validation to work right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/5JT94/

HTML:

```
<p>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipbox"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="formValidation()" value="Submit" /></p>
```

JS:

```
function formValidation()  
{  
var zip=document.getElementById("zipbox");  

function allnumeric(zip)  
{   
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/; 
    if(zip.value.match(numbers))  
    {  
        alert("Everything OK");
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert("Numbers only please");  
    }  
}; 
};
```

Comment: "The code does not do anything when I run it." What should it do?

Comment: You never call `allnumeric()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't executing the function on the zip that you found.

```
var zip=document.getElementById("zipbox");  
allnumeric(zip);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JT94/1/

Comment: Looks like a retaliation downvote. +1 to counteract.

Comment: You also changed the jsfiddle from "onload" to "no wrap - in <head>

Answer (score 0):

And in case you don't want to add an id (can't see why):

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/5JT94/2/)

HTML

```
<form name="zipform">
    <p>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipbox" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

JS

```
function formValidation() {  
    var zip=document.forms["zipform"].elements["zipbox"];
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/; 
    if(zip.value.match(numbers))  {  
        alert("Everything OK");
    } else {  
        alert("Numbers only please");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

document.forms["zipform"].elements["submit"].onclick=formValidation;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems may relate to how jsfiddle works.  I had to add "window.formValidation = formValidation" so that the formValidation function you defined in the onClick would be found.  Second, you had an allnumeric function but it wasn't being called.

```
function formValidation()  
{  
    var zip=document.getElementById("zipbox");  

    function allnumeric(zip)  
    {   
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/; 
        if(zip.value.match(numbers))  
        {  
            alert("Everything OK");
        }  
        else  
        {  
            alert("Numbers only please");  
        }  
    }; 

    allnumeric(zip);
};

window.formValidation = formValidation
```

Answer (score -1):

your element does not have an id ? change like below

```
   <input id="zipbox" type="text" name="zipbox">
```

then debug from there

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: It has id in the fiddle. When debugging I changed it to name and pasted it into my post by accident.